# Get an actual image source if there is a php function in "src" attribute

Tags: php, html, image

How could I being a client fetch the actual name of an image file if it is placed on a page like this:

I need to know at least the name of the file if it is possible.

Comment: You can get the actual image source using simple html dom

Comment: Check [simple html dom](http://www.simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this method is that you can not.  If it's your site then just the the actual `filename` rather than fetching it from a `"php function"`.  If it's not, then maybe you should not try to hack it :-)

Answer (score 0):

View the page in your browser.
Right anywhere ad select View Source Code.
There you can get the actual image name.